# Passing structure by reference in c

Tags: c, function, structure

I am trying to do simple dynamic implementation of stack using link list.
Next is my code. The code has no errors. But changes done inside the function are not reflected back though I believe I'm passing the structure by reference.
Though I have been able to make this work by using global structure, but I'm missing a very basic concept here, so wanted to know what am I understanding wrong and how can I reflect the changes done in pop function back in main without using global scope.

```
struct stack
{
   char value;
   struct stack *next;
};

void push(char a,struct stack *s1)
{
 struct stack *s2;
 s2=(struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
 if(empty(s1))
 {
             s2->value=a;
             s2->next=NULL;
             s1=s2;
 }
 else
 {
     s2->value=a;
     s2->next=s1;
     s1=s2;
 }
 return;
}



int main()
{
struct stack s1;
push(c,&s1);
printf("%d",s1.value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s1=s2;` this might not do what you want. You are modifying your local copy of the stack.

Try

```
void push(char a,struct stack **s1)
{
    struct stack *s2;
    s2=(struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if(empty(*s1))
    {
         s2->value=a;
         s2->next=NULL;
         *s1=s2;
    }
    else
    {
        s2->value=a;
        s2->next=s1;
        *s1=s2;
    }
    return;
}
```

Incidentally, it is mentioned int the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

As Richard Pennington mentions, you need to declare `s1` like so: `struct stack *s1;`.

Comment: @Richard Pennington Right on :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer to stack by value and trying to change it.

Answer (score 0):

As cnicutar said, the s1=s2 is not doing anything useful.  You probably want *s1=*s2;